# Datastax Cassandra Auto Scaling on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed a 9 node DataStax Cassandra Cluster (3 Data Centers) in Google Cloud.

Does anyone has done auto scaling ( Adding new nodes and removing the nodes) based on Load?

In Google Cloud i saw how to add auto scaling but doesnt know how to add to cluster.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Unless you aren't planning on keeping more than a few MB per node, auto-scaling based on load is not really something Cassandra was designed for. You have to consider bootstrapping and what that means for Cassandra. It's really a physics problem - by the time your node gets added and can serve traffic, the load may have changed for better or worse. 

Scaling based on node density is a bit more realistic but I'm not sure how that's done on Google Cloud (which is why I'm not posting this in the answers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just thought of checking does any one has implemented in Google Cloud(Auto Scaling). Planning to try in test environment.